# Prove that for all positive integer n, the inequality $2n\choose n$ $<4^n$ holds

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, binomial-coefficients

How do I prove that for all positive integer n, the inequality $2n\choose n$$<4^n$ holds?

Thank you!

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448861/prove-that-2n-binom2nn-22n and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/931306/inequality-binom2nn-leq-4n

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint:  The LHS is the number of $n$-element subsets of $[2n]$, while the RHS is the number of all subsets of $[2n]$.

Comment: Thanks you! But how do I set the equations up?

Comment: @Emile You can use this hint the following way: $4^n=(1+1)^{2n} =\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} > \binom{2n}{n}$.

Comment: @emile N.S. said it, I was just about to type it, oh by the way, what have you tried?