# Proof that ${{2n}\choose{n}} > 2^n$ and ${{2n + 1}\choose{n}} > 2^{n+1}$, with $n > 1$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

i'm trying to proof these two terms. I started with an induction, but I got stuck...

Can anybody help?

Comment: related : [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448861/prove-that-2n-binom2nn-22n)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is easy:

$\displaystyle
{{2n}\choose{n}}
= \frac{2n}{n} \frac{2n-1}{n-1} \cdots \frac{n+1}{1}
> 2 \cdot 2 \cdots 2 = 2^n
$

The second one needs Pascal's relation and induction:

$\displaystyle
{{2n+1}\choose{n}}
= {{2n}\choose{n}} + {{2n}\choose{n-1}}
$

$\displaystyle\qquad\qquad
= {{2n}\choose{n}} + {{2n-1}\choose{n-1}} + {{2n-1}\choose{n-2}}
$

$\displaystyle\qquad\qquad
> {{2n}\choose{n}} + {{2n-1}\choose{n-1}}
$

$\displaystyle\qquad\qquad
> 2^n + 2^n = 2^{n+1}
$

Comment: 2nd greater than in induction not very clear.

Comment: @underdog, $2n-1=2(n-1)+1$.

Comment: ah and ${{2(n-1)+1}\choose {n-1}}=2{{2(n-1)}\choose {n-1}}\gt 2(2^{n-1})=2^n$

Comment: @underdog, no. I meant this: ${{2n-1}\choose{n-1}}={{2(n-1)+1}\choose {n-1}} > 2^{(n-1)+1}$.

Comment: yes.  i know. 6-1 half dozen-other.  one twice the other per twice as many subsets with $+1$ element.  actually i don't follow without claiming one twice the other.

Answer (score 2):

Induction works pretty well, since:
$$\frac{\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}{\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{4n+2}{n+1}=2\cdot\frac{2n+1}{n+1}\geq 3 $$
and:
$$\frac{\binom{2n+3}{n+1}}{\binom{2n+1}{n}}=2\cdot\frac{2n+3}{n+2}\geq 3$$
as soon as $n\geq 1$.

Comment: that's cool.  never seen induction done like that.  so base case and then assumption and then times $3+\gt$ times $2$