# Show that $2^n ≤$ $n\choose n/2$ is contradictory

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing

I am writing a proof and I am having issues with this part of the proof. I want to show that $2^n ≤$ $n\choose n/2$ is contradictory.

Comment: You mean, you want to show $2^{2m}>{2m\choose m}$?

Comment: What is C(n/2)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $2^n &lt; \binom{2n}{n} &lt; 2^{2n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448861/prove-that-2n-binom2nn-22n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clear by a very simple combinatorial argument: Say $S=\{1,2\dots,n\}$. Then $2^n$ is the total number of subsets of $S$, while $C(n,n/2)$ is...

Comment: Is C(n,n/2) is the number of elements chosen from set S?

Comment: Ah okay i get it! The combination of elements chosen from set S will always be a subset of the total number of subsets possible, hence it is not possible for the combination of elements chosen from set S to be greater than the total number of subsets possible

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$ (1+1)^{2m}=\sum_{k=0}^{2m}{2m\choose k}1^k1^{2m-k}$$