# Inequality $\binom{2n}{n}\leq 4^n$

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients, alternative-proof

I would like to prove the following inequality, for $n=0,1,2,...$,   $$ \binom{2n}{n}\leq 4^n.$$ I already proved it by induction, and I'm looking for another proof.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$\displaystyle 4^n=(1+1)^{2n} =\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}\geq\binom{2n}{n}$

Answer (score 13):

A bit more can be proven with a bit more work. For $k\ge0$, we have the inequality
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{k+\frac12}{k+1}\right)^2
&=\frac{k^2+k+\frac14}{k^2+2k+1}\\
&\le\frac{k+1}{k+2}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
because cross-multiplication gives $k^3+3k^2+\frac94k+\frac12\le k^3+3k^2+3k+1$.

Using $(1)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\binom{2k+2}{k+1}}{\binom{2k}{k}}
&=4\frac{k+\frac12}{k+1}\\
&\le4\sqrt{\frac{k+1}{k+2}}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Multiplying $(2)$ for $k=0$ to $k=n-1$, we get
$$
\boxed{\bbox[5px]{\displaystyle\binom{2n}{n}\le\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{n+1}}}}\tag{3}
$$

---

As Olivier Oloa comments, Stirling's Formula tells us that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{4^n}=1\tag{4}
$$
In fact, using inequalities similar to $(2)$, in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/932509), it is shown that
$$
\boxed{\bbox[5pt]{\displaystyle\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi(n+\frac13)}}\le\binom{2n}{n}\le\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi(n+\frac14)}}}}\tag{5}$$

Comment: Nice inequality, especially knowing that the true order is $$
\binom{2n}{n}\sim \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{n}}.
$$(+1)

Comment: @OlivierOloa: We actually have that $$\binom{2n}{n}\frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{4^n}\nearrow1$$ which means that $\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ is an overestimate as well as an asymptotic approximation. Come to think of it, I can prove this using a similar argument and Stirling's Formula. Time for an edit :-)

Answer (score 6):

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}.$ You may write

$$
4^n=2^{2n} =(1+1)^{2n}= \sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}\geq\binom{2n}{n}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{{2n \choose n}\leq 4^{n}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> \binom{2n}{n}&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{2n} \over z^{n + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
\color{#66f}{\large\verts{\binom{2n}{n}}}&=
\verts{\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{2n} \over z^{n + 1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}
\\[5mm] \leq &
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\verts{\pars{1 + z}^{2n}}
\,{\verts{\dd z} \over 2\pi}<\pars{1 + 1}^{2n}=\color{#66f}{\LARGE 4^{n}}
\end{align}