# What is value of limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2}$ I tried a lot but I haven't desired result. I tried with sandwich theorem

Comment: Use Stirling approximation of the factorial.

Comment: You tried to sandwich with what?

Comment: "I tried a lot" Excellent! Now, just show two or three of the things you tried. "but I haven't desired result" No problem, just show the result(s) you got and the result you would have *desired* to get.

Comment: BTW: what is the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The estimations

$\frac{4^{n}}{\sqrt{4n}} \leq {2n \choose n} \leq \frac{4^{n}}{\sqrt {3n+1}}$  for $n \ge 1$ can be found here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient

Comment: How can the inequality be proven?

Answer (score 4):

**First Approach**

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/932509), it is shown that
$$
\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi\left(n+\frac13\right)}}\le\binom{2n}{n}\le\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi\left(n+\frac14\right)}}
$$

---

**Another Approach**

Squaring and cross multiplying show that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\,\frac{(2n)!}{4^{n}n!^2}\,}{\frac{(2n-2)!}{4^{n-1}(n-1)!^2}}
&=\frac{2n-1}{2n}\\
&\le\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(2n)!}{4^{n}n!^2}
&=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k-1}{2k}\\
&\le\prod_{k=1}^n\sqrt{\frac{k}{k+1}}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac1{n+1}}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: The second approach is so nice ! Thanks for providing such answers.

Comment: The proof of the estimate in the first approach is very similar to the second approach. In fact, we can also get the tighter bounds $$\sqrt{\frac{4n-3}{4n+1}}\le\frac{2n-1}{2n}\le\sqrt{\frac{3n-2}{3n+1}}$$ which gives that the ratio in the question is between $\sqrt{\frac1{4n+1}}$ and $\sqrt{\frac1{3n+1}}$

Answer (score 3):

By De Moivre's formula $2\cos\theta=e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}$ and the binomial theorem we have
$$\frac{(2n)!}{4^n n!^2}=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\cos \theta\right)^{2n}\,d\theta $$
hence the wanted limit is zero by the dominated/monotone convergence theorem.

---

Alternative approach: by letting $a_n=\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}$ we have
$$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{4(n+1)^2}=\frac{n+\frac{1}{2}}{n+1}\leq\sqrt{\frac{n+\frac{1}{2}}{n+\frac{3}{2}}} $$
$$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_0}=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\cdot\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}\cdots\frac{a_1}{a_0}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+3}} $$
and $a_n\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$ is the number of $2n$-digit binary numbers with exactly $n$ zeros and $n$ ones.  Second, note that $2^{2n} = 4^n$ is the number of $2n$-digit binary numbers.  So the limit is "clearly" $0$.

See the second answer to this:

[Inequality $\binom{2n}{n}\leq 4^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/931306/inequality-binom2nn-leq-4n)